# Why does my python script not keep listening

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Hello stackoverflow users, so I have this problem where i am trying to code a web server but the script ends before I can even test if it works. So my question is how can I make the script so that it will keep running forever?

```
#import threading
#import socket
#import signal  # Signal support (server shutdown on signal receive)
import multiprocessing
#import queue

def MasterProcessA():
    import socket
    import multiprocessing
    import threading
    HOST = '97.107.139.231'   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
    PORT = 8080 # Arbitrary non-privileged port
    #print(PORT)
    socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #print 'Socket created'

    #Bind socket to local host and port
    #try:
    socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    #except socket.error as msg:
    ##print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    #print 'Socket bind complete'

    #Start listening on socket
    socket.listen(100)
    print "starting server"
    def ConnProcessA():
        print "thread step one"
        Conn, Address = socket.accept()
        t = threading.Thread(target=ConnectionProcessorA)
        print "thread step two"
        #t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        #print("A Got connection from:", Address)
        DataRecived = Conn.recv(1024) #receive data from client
        DataRecived = bytes.decode(DataRecived) #decode it to string
        print DataRecived
        Conn.send("HELLO World")
        Conn.clouse()

    ConnProcessA = threading.Thread(target=ConnProcessA)
    #t.daemon = True
    ConnProcessA.start()

MasterProcessA = multiprocessing.Process(target=MasterProcessA)
MasterProcessA.start()
```

Comment: Where exactly does it end?

Comment: use a while loop? :)

Comment: This is the whole script and i do not know where to implement the while loop

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: I know when to use the while loop i just do not know where to place it inside of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your codes.

- The thread doesn't run. You need to modify:

  `ConnProcessA.start()
  ConnProcessA.join()`
- `ConnectionProcessorA` is not included in the codes you pasted. So I have to comment out these 2 lines:

  `t = threading.Thread(target=ConnectionProcessorA)
  t.start()`
- Name shadowing. Refer to these lines:

  `socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  ConnProcessA = threading.Thread(target=ConnProcessA)
  MasterProcessA = multiprocessing.Process(target=MasterProcessA)`
- You named instances with existing module/function names. Name shadowing is very dangerous. Just try to execute any of the 3 lines twice, you will see the error.
- On the other side, it's ok to reuse a variable to hold different things, if straightforward enough. E.g., following two lines are close enough to avoid confusion:

  `DataRecived = Conn.recv(1024) #receive data from client
  DataRecived = bytes.decode(DataRecived) #decode it to string`
- Seems your socket server is to continuously listen to a same port, then you probably need to add `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`. As said at the most bottom of [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).
- A less severe point, in Python coding convention, CapWords is usually used for class names [ref](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names). You used it for both function names and variable names. Better to keep your codes consistent.